# Angular velocity - Gyroscope

Tags: angular-momentum, mass, torque, angular-velocity, gyroscopes

I am currently researching the gyroscope on my own and i came across the concept of angular velocity.

The torque ($T$) on a gyroscope is caused by $R\cdot F$, where the force i consider it to be equal to $mg$.

Since $T = \frac{dL}{dt}$ and $L = I\cdot ω$

where $L$-angular momentum, $t$-time, $I$-moment of inertia, $\omega$-angular velocity
and $I = mR^2$

If i decrease the mass of the gyroscope, this means that over the same time period the change in $L$ will be decrease as well.

However I also depends on the mass and will decrease by the same amount (?).

Does this mean that $\omega$ will always be the same? If so why?

Comment: Your two statements are the same statement. Decreasing the mass reduces $L$ because $I$ is less. So what _is_ your question?

Answer (score 0):

> If i decrease the mass of the gyroscope, this means that over the same time period the change in L will decrease as well.

We have to be aware that in the textbook description of **gyroscopic precession**, the magnitude of $\vec L$ is assumed to be **constant** despite it may have changing direction. Thus, we can only use $\dfrac{d\vec L}{dt}$ to say that the change in $L$'s **direction** will decrease as the mass decreases.

> However I also depends on the mass and will decrease by the same amount (?).

Not by same amount but by **same proportion** so that the **precession rate** of the gyroscope $\Omega$, defined by
$\Omega=$$\dfrac{d\phi}{dt}=\frac{Mgr}{I\omega}$, is **independent of the mass** of the gyroscope.

(Hint: $d\phi=\dfrac{dL}{L}$)

> Does this mean that $\omega$ will always be the same? If so why?

$\omega$ is independent of $M$. As said above, $L$ is regarded to be constant, thus $I\omega$ is constant, so $\omega$ won't change.